# select values from multiple tables where value = X

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to perform what I assume is a very simple query on a MySQL DB. Here's my table setup;

**Table 1 - CMS_AccessLevels**

- accessLevel
- titleColor

**Table 2 - CMS_Users**

- userID
- username
- userEmail
- userAvatar
- userSignature
- accessLevel

I've already got this query;

```
SELECT `titleColor` FROM `CMS_AccessLevels` WHERE `accessLevel` = (SELECT `accessLevel` FROM `CMS_Users` WHERE `userID` = 3)
```

This works correctly and returns the correct `titleColor` value based on the `accessLevel` matching across both tables.

Now, what I want to do is also grab some of the values from `CMS_Users` as well. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume I want to grab only a few of the values, so my result set might look something like this;

```
userID|username|userAvatar|accessLevel|titleColor
-------------------------------------------------
0     |Scott   |image.png | 6         |#FFFFFF
```

or as a PHP Array (shown just so you can see the logical layout if the above table didn't make sense);

```
array('userID' => $result['userID'],
      'username' => $result['username'],
      'userAvatar' => $result['userAvatar'],
      'accessLevel' => $result['accessLevel'],
      'titleColor' => $result['titleColor'];
```

Let's say I want to get `userID`, `userName`, `userAvatar` and `accessLevel` from **`CMS_Users`**, and `titleColor` from **`CMS_AccessLevels`** where `CMS_Users.userID` is equal to '3', remembering that `CMS_AccessLevels.accessLevel` and `CMS_Users.accessLevel` **MUST** match.

Realistically, the only piece of data I know before running the query is `userID`.

**Is it possible to do this with a single query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.userID, u.username, u.userAvatar, u.accessLevel,  al.titleColor
FROM CMS_AccessLevels al
INNER JOIN CMS_Users u
ON u.accessLevel = al.accessLevel
WHERE u.userID = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using subqueries whereas joins will be the right choice. You might try something like

```
SELECT a.titleColor AS titleColor, u.username AS username FROM CMS_users u INNER JOIN CMS_AccessLevels a ON u.accessLevel = a.accessLevel WHERE u.userID = '3'
```